# Why are some YAML keys and values highlighted oddly?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, syntax-highlighting

In Visual Studio Code (1.22.2) when I add certain words to a YAML file they are syntax highlighted differently to what is expected.

For example both `on` and `y` are colored orange here. AFAIK, neither `on` nor `y` have any special YAML significance. This occurs for other keys and values also. I note this same color is used on *values* of `true` or `false` but here it is occurring for seemingly arbitrary values and also for keys. The same occurs after a restart with all extensions disabled so it's not some forgotten extension I don't think.

[image: screen grab of syntax highlighted text in vscode]

Is this some other file-type syntax-highlighter interfering? Am I missing something about YAML 'keywords'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In YAML 1.1, there are actually many values recognized as booleans, and `on` and `y` belong to them.

See the type specification for `!!bool` in the YAML 1.1 type repository: http://yaml.org/type/bool.html

I wrote this overview of Types/Schema in YAML 1.1/1.2 a while ago, maybe this is helpful too:
http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/01/introduction-to-yaml-schemas-and-tags.html

One of the bigger changes in 1.2 was that less values are recognized as booleans.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, thanks (your blog post looks very helpful!). But does it make sense that these values are recognised when used as keys as well as values?

Comment: Yeah, booleans as keys can make sense, if the language does support that.